# ayuda error datatable destoy

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tengo un problema con mi tabla, al momento que la llamo para cargar (cuando inserto algo llamo la tabla para que lo actualice al momento), me marca como un error o aviso, tengo q destruir la tabla y volverla a construir pero no se como hacer eso me marca esto:
[image: error aviso]

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {

         html+= '<tr><td class="center">'+data[i].fecha_registro+
            '</td><td class="center">'+dias+
            '</td><td class="center">'+data[i].nombre+
            '</td><td class="center">'+data[i].modelo+
            '</td><td class="center" data-id="'+data[i].id+'"><span data-id="'+data[i].id+'"class="label ' + colorear(data[i].ser,'col_ser') + '">'+data[i].ser+
            '</span></td><td class="center"><span data-id="'+data[i].id+'" data-auto="'+data[i].modelo+'" class="label ' + colorear(data[i].se,'col_se') +'">'+data[i].se+
            '</span></td></tr>';
    }
    $('#body_valuaciones').html(html);

    $('#table_valuaciones').dataTable( {

                    "bPaginate":false,
                     "bAutoWidth": true,

    } );
    $('.dataTables_filter input').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "Buscar");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la tabla ya existe, puedes hacer esto:

```
var table = $('#table_valuaciones').DataTable();

table.destroy();

$('#table_valuaciones').dataTable( {

                "bPaginate":false,
                 "bAutoWidth": true,

} );
```

Comment: no debe de ir antes de que empiece a  hacer la tabla?, si, cuando entro a la pagina ya carga la tabla

Comment: Si la tabla ya existe, la primera linea de mi respuesta no empieza la tabla, simplemente guarda la tabla que ya existe en la variable `table`.

Comment: es que me marca error dice: table.destroy is not a function